# MySQL Joining Tables While Counting & Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 2 tables:

```
source_table
 ----------------------------------
| source_id    label               |
|----------------------------------|
| 1            Contact Form        |
| 2            E-Mail              |
| 3            Inbound Call        |
| 4            Referral            |
 ----------------------------------

related_table
 ---------------------------------------
| id           created_at       source  |
|---------------------------------------|
| 1            2013-12-26       2       |
| 2            2013-12-26       2       |
| 3            2013-12-26       4       |
| 4            2013-12-25       1       |
| 5            2013-12-18       2       |
| 6            2013-12-16       4       |
| 7            2013-11-30       2       |
 ---------------------------------------
```

So that it looks like this:

```
 ---------------------------------------
| created_at   source           amount  |
|---------------------------------------|
| 2013-12-26   E-Mail           2       |
| 2013-12-26   Referral         1       |
| 2013-12-25   Contact Form     1       |
| 2013-12-18   E-Mail           1       |
| 2013-12-16   Referral         1       |
 ---------------------------------------
```

**I want to count the occurrences of each source in `related_table` grouped by the source for each date in the range.**

But I'm not sure how to write the query.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  source_table.source_id,
  source_table.label AS source, 
  related_table.created_at,
  COUNT(*) AS amount

FROM source_table
  INNER JOIN related_table
    ON related_table.source=source_table.source_id AND
    related_table.created_at>='2013-12-01' AND 
    related_table.created_at<='2013-12-31'

GROUP BY `source` 
ORDER BY `created_at` ASC
```

---

I'm not very good with SQL, so the above query might be far off from what I need to have. All I know is that it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: why are you joining on a specific set of dates?

Comment: That's just for mock purposes. The date range will be changing. The scenario is to count the number of incoming sales lead sources organized by type over a given range of time.

Comment: Also, can you add a couple of rows to your example data? Add an example on related table where source=2 and created_at is not '2013-12-26' -- what would your results look like in that example? Depending on that, it would change the way the sql would work.

Comment: The date criteria belongs in a "where" clause, not an "on" clause -- it'll work either way, but for readability and perhaps optimization, it should be in the where clause.

Comment: @JoeLove I've added more data as you requested. The dates on where clause makes sense, as I may want to join additional tables like `related_table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation:

```
select created_at, s.label, amount
from 
(
    select count(r.Source) as amount, r.source, r.created_at
    from  related_table r
    group by r.source, r.created_at) a  inner join source_table s
   on a.source = s.source_id
where created_at between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-31'
order by amount desc, created_at desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/841bd/2

adjusted  demo to your example...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Although this query ultimately needs to be generated through working with Magento collections (meaning I can't easily re-produce a sub-query short of direct SQL), it does work according to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  created_at
  ,label as source
  ,COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM source_table
INNER JOIN related_table
ON source_table.source_id = related_table.source 
GROUP BY label, created_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: This did not work as needed, sorry. See @Milen Pavlov's answer.